# Mongoose Connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read the quick start from [the Mongoose website](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) and I almost copy the code, but I cannot connect the MongoDB using Node.js.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

exports.test = function(req, res) {
  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
  console.log("h1");
  db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log("h");
  });
  res.render('test');
};
```

This is my code. The console only prints `h1`, not `h`. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you call `mongoose.connect`, it will set up a connection with the database.

However, you attach the event listener for `open` at a much later point in time (when a request is being handled), meaning that the connection is probably already active and the `open` event has already been called (you just weren't yet listening for it).

You should rearrange your code so that the event handler is as close (in time) to the connect call as possible:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log("h");
});

exports.test = function(req,res) {
  res.render('test');
};
```

Comment: It should first listen on events, then establish connection. The sequence is opposite

Comment: @xwa130 async much?

Answer (score 14):

> The safest way to do this, it to "listen for the connect event". This way you don't care how long it takes for the DB to give you a connection.
>
> Once that is done - you should start the server. Also.. config.MONGOOSE is exposed across your app, so you only have one DB connection.
>
> If you want to use mongoose's connection, simply require config in your module, and call config.Mongoose.  Hope this helps out someone!
>
> Here's the code.

```
var mongoURI;

mongoose.connection.on("open", function(ref) {
  console.log("Connected to mongo server.");
  return start_up();
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log("Could not connect to mongo server!");
  return console.log(err);
});

mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost/dbanme";

config.MONGOOSE = mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
```

Comment: This code is more reliable then the accepted answer, while the accepted answer explains more clearly.

Comment: This helped a lot. I was certain the problem was my connection string, because I always have trouble with that the first time I use a new database. This code gave me the confirmation of the problem I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Mongoose connection using Singleton Pattern

Mongoose Connection File - db.js

```
//Import the mongoose module
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

class Database { // Singleton
  connection = mongoose.connection;
  
  constructor() {
    try {
      this.connection
      .on('open', console.info.bind(console, 'Database connection: open'))
      .on('close', console.info.bind(console, 'Database connection: close'))
      .on('disconnected', console.info.bind(console, 'Database connection: disconnecting'))
      .on('disconnected', console.info.bind(console, 'Database connection: disconnected'))
      .on('reconnected', console.info.bind(console, 'Database connection: reconnected'))
      .on('fullsetup', console.info.bind(console, 'Database connection: fullsetup'))
      .on('all', console.info.bind(console, 'Database connection: all'))
      .on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection: error:'));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async connect(username, password, dbname) {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(
        `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@cluster0.2a7nn.mongodb.net/${dbname}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
        {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async close() {
    try {
      await this.connection.close();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = new Database();
```

call the connection from app.js

```
const express = require("express"); // Express Server Framework

const Database = require("./utils/db");

const app = express();

Database.connect("username", "password", "dbname");

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error popping up. Then I found out that I didn't have a mongod running and listening for connections. To do that you just need to open another command prompt (cmd) and run mongod

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose's default connection logic is deprecated as of 4.11.0. It is recommended to use the new connection logic:

- useMongoClient option
- native promise library

---

Here is the example from npm module: **[mongoose-connect-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-connect-db)**

```
// Connection options
const defaultOptions = {
  // Use native promises (in driver)
  promiseLibrary: global.Promise,
  useMongoClient: true,
  // Write concern (Journal Acknowledged)
  w: 1,
  j: true
};

function connect (mongoose, dbURI, options = {}) {
  // Merge options with defaults
  const driverOptions = Object.assign(defaultOptions, options);

  // Use Promise from options (mongoose)
  mongoose.Promise = driverOptions.promiseLibrary;

  // Connect
  mongoose.connect(dbURI, driverOptions);

  // If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection
  process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    mongoose.connection.close(() => {
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });

  return mongoose.connection;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the advise. Added an example

Answer (score 0):

**A simple way i make a connection:**

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

```
mongoose.connect(<connection string>);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.on("error", error => {
    console.log('Problem connection to the database'+error);
});
```