# How to count instances of specific field in a mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is the payment collection in my mongodb.

```
{
studentIDnumber: "111"
datepicker: "02/06/2019"
transactType: "Graduation expenses"
timepicker:"11:00am - 12:00pm"
amount:"123"
}

{
studentIDnumber: "111"
datepicker: "02/03/2019"
transactType: "Diploma"
timepicker:"11:00am - 12:00pm"
amount:"123"
}

{
studentIDnumber: "111"
datepicker: "02/03/2019"
transactType: "Tuition fee"
timepicker:"11:00am - 12:00pm"
amount:"123"
}
```

I'm trying to count how many 11:00 - 12:00pm in the collection but it gave me an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`, below is my nodejs code. What would be the correct way to do this? Any ideas?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const url = require('../config/keys').MongoURI

router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>{
  res.render('dashboard', {
    firstname: req.user.firstname,
    lastname : req.user.lastname
  }),

  mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err
    db.payments.count({timepicker: "11:00am - 12:00pm"})

  })

});
```

Comment: You don't need to each time connect to the database. Once you connect then mongoose constructor adds it as Global.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360531/mongoose-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query :

```
db.payments.find({timepicker: "11:00am - 12:00pm"}).count(function(err, count) 
    {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(count);

    });
```

if you are using mongoose , then

```
 PaymentModel.count({timepicker: "11:00am - 12:00pm"}, function(err, c) {
       console.log('Count is ' + c);
  });
```

Comment: it worked! but i just replaced the count to countDocuments because I got a warning that it will be deprecated.